# What causes this error "'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'findAll'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I cant share the page but  this is the sample html code that i wanna access

```html
<tr ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" class="hand_cursor ng-scope" title="View Details" style="">
        <td class="ng-binding">96685</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Alvarado, Jacqueline C.</td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">Nov 6, 2017</td>
        <td align="right" class="ng-binding">A1054</td>
                                <td align="right" class="ng-binding">A1054 - A1054</td>
                                <td align="right" class="ng-binding">87004000</td>
       </tr>
<tr ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" class="hand_cursor ng-scope" title="View Details">
        <td class="ng-binding">33522</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">Bailey, Jacqueline B.</td>
                                <td class="ng-binding">Jan 16, 1992</td>
        <td align="right" class="ng-binding">DL-46</td>
                                <td align="right" class="ng-binding">DL-46 - DL-46</td>
                                <td align="right" class="ng-binding">81313001</td>
       </tr>
```

This is the code that im trying to run. What in trying to do is access the 2nd td in the first tr that i targeted. My expected result should be the Name text in side the 2nd td

```
test_words = ['Jacqueline','abercrombie']
    test_word = ['STEVEN']


    # test_words = ['STEVEN','(',')','-','69807','21490','321']
    for i in test_words:
        search = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/tabletoolstrans/div/input')
        search.clear()
        search.send_keys(i)
        search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(3)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source,"html.parser")
        for item in soup.findAll("tr", {"class": "hand_cursor ng-scope"})[1]:
            for td in item.findAll("td")[1]:
                if td == i:
                    print("Search :"+i+"")
                    buttons.save_csv(self, "Pass")
                else:
                    print("Fail")
        print("jaq")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: post page address and desired output

Comment: i have added a html snippet that i wanna access

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: The error means that you called "findAll" on a leaf text node instead of an element node. I don't see it in your code but it could be in `buttons.save_csv`. Can you post the full stack trace so we can see which line failed?

Comment: i have added the expected result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `item` is a NavigableString object which contains the value `\n`. A NavigableString is just a bit of text on the page whereas you are presumably expecting a list of `td` items based on your code. To read more about NavigableStrings see here:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring

I think the issue here is with the array notation (`[0]`) at the end of your findAll's. You correctly get all of the `tr`'s, then take only one using the array notation, and then loop through the result of that which is a single tr object at this point. Result of that is the `td` tags and the newline spaces between.

In short, get rid of the `[0]` ;)

End code i believe should be...

```
test_words = ['Jacqueline','abercrombie']
test_word = ['STEVEN']

for i in test_words:
    search = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-wrapper"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/tabletoolstrans/div/input')
    search.clear()
    search.send_keys(i)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source,"html.parser")
    for item in soup.findAll("tr", {"class": "hand_cursor ng-scope"}):
        for td in item.findAll("td"):
            if td.text == i:
                print("Search :"+i+"")
                buttons.save_csv(self, "Pass")
            else:
                print("Fail")
    print("jaq")
time.sleep(3)
```

Note - also added `.text` to this line in order to get the contents of the tag.

```
if td.text == i:
```

Comment: but i only want to get the 2nd td of the first tr

Comment: In that case, you do want array notation but need to drop the loop. One or the other not both :) your findAll lines should become... 
`item = soup.findAll("tr", {"class": "hand_cursor ng-scope"})[0]` and `td = item.findAll("td")[1]`

Comment: yes yes i have tried that and it worked .. thank you :)